# Can I create a local backup of my cloud files on my desktop computer?

Tags: raspberry-pi, synchronization, backup, owncloud

Let me start by saying that I have setup a personal owncloud server on a raspberry pi. I did so by following this tutorial. https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-owncloud/comment-page-1/#comments

The server works the same as dropbox or onedrive type system that syncs my files across multiple devices. I do work on two different computers and enjoy the syncing. I chose to setup a personal server as a side project and to avoid paying another service.

I do not have a lot of experience with networking in general so I am afraid that in the event of a failure of the server all my files will be lost. Is there a way to create a backup folder of the owncloud server data to local disk on my desktop? Preferably to a zipped folder that backups only every few days or so?